# What are the requirements for publishing code as nuget

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

Having studied several sources such as

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli

I am still lacking information as to which requirements a package must fulfill. I understand most of them are packed libraries, but am I allowed to publish let's say my own collection of code snippets that I gathered or collected over the years as let's say `benj.kickasssnippets` for which no documentation (other than maybe the code itself in a tumbleweed github repo) will ever exist and for which nobody other than me will ever have use?

I find it hard to believe that there are none such requirements and Microsoft not being concerned about filling their storage up with half empty *Hello World from a Nuget Library*-Projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: Are there any "requirements" to create your own NuGet package and publish it on your own NuGet repo?

A: No, absolutely not.

Q: Does NuGet.org have policies regarding terms and conditions?

A: Yes: https://www.nuget.org/policies/Terms

You'll also, of course, need to register and get an API key before you publish anything to NuGet.org.